# Access property of current class, such as background-color, in SASS

Tags: sass

I keep finding myself wanting to refer to a property of the current class when working in SASS. Usually this comes up as a way to make things more reusable or handle interactions. For example:

```
.circle
  background-color: $brandColor
.circle:hover
  background-color: $brandColor + 50
.square
  background-color: $brandColor1
.square:hover
  background-color: $brandColor1 + 50
```

I would prefer to write the code more DRYly, like this:

```
.circle
  background-color: $brandColor
.square
  background-color: $brandColor1
.circle:hover,
.square:hover
  background-color: &background-color + 50
```

Is this, or something similar, possible in SASS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is nothing like that in Sass.  You would need to use a mixin to get the DRYness you're looking for.

```
@mixin colorize($color) {
    background-color: $color;

    &:hover {
        background-color: $color + 50;
    }
}

.circle {
  @include colorize($brandColor1);
}
.square {
  @include colorize($brandColor2);
}
```

Comment: A good solution for the stated problem. Where this comes up in production is more complex. Things like wanting to reuse those keyframe definitions for any color: https://gist.github.com/SimpleAsCouldBe/5751159

Comment: I still don't see the problem there.  You just need a mixin with another argument for the color.  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/5751513

Comment: Wow, that's beautiful, you can reuse the box shadow layer declaration, I didn't think of that. Still can't reuse the same keyframe definition for a different color, but I suppose that's a css limitation not a sass one.